# One word for "to give a sense of"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to say that showing my students a picture of the temple gave them a sense of the setting in which a story took place, and allowed them to better understand the story. 
Any ideas for "to get a sense of"?
Thanks!
SL

Answer (score 5):

You could say that the picture of the temple [**evoked**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evoke) (a sense of) what it was like to actually be there.

Answer (score 2):

*[Conjure](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conjure)*:

> noun
>
> 1.2 Call (an image) to the mind:
>
> 1.3 (Of a word, sound, smell, etc.) cause someone to think of (something):
>
> ODO

*This picture will **conjure** the setting of the events in your mind.*